# поиск картинок на питоне, и могут ли быть проблемы из-за этого

Tags: python, ip

дело в том что я создал бота в дискорде, который по запросу ищет в гугле картинку к примеру: .найди дом; и отправится картинка дома из google pictures. Но дело не в этом, а что если боту отправят какой-нибудь запрещенный запрос, который преследуется по закону. Могут ли быть из-за этого проблемы с законом? Так как бот же мой, и запросы все идут с моего ip

Comment: google pictures по идее не выдает что-то прям запрещенное, они сами блокируют очень многое. В целом, я очень сомневаюсь, что за запрос могут как-то привлечь (по крайней мере, пока), разве что за распространение какой-то запрещенной информации (если пользователи через бот будут что-то постить, а не просто получать информацию из поисковика). Но если так уж сильно боитесь - удалите бота. А так если захотят привлечь - любая найденная рандомная флешка у вас дома может быть использована против вас, как доказательство, что вы злобный хакер.

Comment: Да, проблемы могут быть с этим теоретически. Хотя вы можете отправлять запросы зашифрованные, по `https`, но кажется это тоже не всегда спасает. В теории проблемы могут быть даже к примеру в случае, если от вашего домашнего `wi-fi` кто-то пароль угадает и будет с него в интернет ходить. Но на практике такого вроде ещё не было. )

Comment: у меня запросы и так через htttps

Comment: ну думаю врядли будут какие-то проблемы, притом я могу все объяснить, что мой бот для поиска картинок, и не был создан для чего то незаконного

Comment: так же и вирусы могут делать, отправлять кучу подозрительных запросов, но так никто не делает, потому что скорее всего это не опасно